# `gpg: keyserver send failed: No keyserver available` when sending to hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net

Tags: gpg-signature, keyserver

I'm using the below command

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys <MY-8-DIGIT-SIGNATURE>
```

as per guided by this article https://getstream.io/blog/publishing-libraries-to-mavencentral-2021/

However, when I try it, it reports

```
gpg: sending key <MY-16-DIGIT-SIGNATURE> to hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver send failed: No keyserver available
gpg: keyserver send failed: No keyserver available
```

What's wrong with my command above?

**Update findings**
This works on macOS Catalina, Intel Core i7 machine.
But it doesn't work on macOS Big Sur, M1 ARM64 machine.

Not sure if it is Big Sur or M1 ARM64 machine issue?

Comment: I have also raised a question to GPG support https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/feedback/16485-gpg-recv-keys-and-send-keys-not-working-on-macos-big-sur-m1-machine

Comment: I have BigSur and an i9 intel processor with the same issue

Answer (score 12):

Found a workaround to the issue.

First I kill the `dirmngr` using command

```
gpgconf --kill dirmngr
```

Then, I start `dirmngr` with `--standard-resolver`

```
dirmngr --debug-all --daemon --standard-resolver
```

Finally, on another terminal, I run

```
gpg --verbose --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x0A292B5F8A3C247F586F19D7E1AF518CC4B1DC35
```

And this gives me the result of

```
gpg: key E1AF518CC4B1DC35: "Kristof (GPGTools) <[email blocked]>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Not sure why I need the `--standard-resolver`, but it works for my case.

**UPDATE**

Found a better way to have the `standard-resolver` by default for dirmngr. This is just by adding `standard-resolver` to `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` file.

Answer (score 11):

https://sks-keyservers.net/
"**This service is deprecated.** This means it is no longer maintained, and new HKPS certificates will not be issued. Service reliability should not be expected.

**Update 2021-06-21:** Due to even more GDPR takedown requests, the DNS records for the pool will no longer be provided at all."

**Update 2021-06-21:** You can use an alternative server such as:

- keyserver.ubuntu.com
- keys.openpgp.org
- pgp.mit.edu

With somethin like this:

`gpg --keyserver keys.openpgp.org --send-key [key id]`

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem.it worked for me

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 34893610CEAA9512
```

you can use script

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a keyservers=(
    "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80"
    "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
    "ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net"
    "hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80"
    "p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net"
    "hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80"
    "pgp.mit.edu"
    "hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80"
)

keys=$(apt update 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-Z]\{16\}$')

for key in $keys; do
    for server in "${keyservers[@]}"; do
        echo "Fetching GPG key ${key} from ${server}"
        gpg --keyserver $server --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys ${key}
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Key '${key}' successful added from server '${server}'"
            break
        else
            echo "Failed add key '${key}' from server '${server}'. Try another server"
            continue
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Tried it without hkp:// and :80 at first, got the same error. Only worked with the full URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to send my keys to the 3 keyservers supported by OSSRH Central Servers:

- keyserver.ubuntu.com
- keys.openpgp.org
- pgp.mit.edu

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i hadn't installed gnupg2. Using this command resolved the issue for me

```
sudo apt install gnupg2
```