# Unable to Install GPG keys

Tags: rvm, gnupg

I want to install rvm follow the [offical document](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), but when i run the below command, got the error `gpg: 从公钥服务器接收失败：No route to host`. Why the command is not work for me.

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

I also try other command, but still got the same error.

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

```
gpg --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67251078/2483313